# Multiple partial views based on same model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have something like this:

Main view:

```
@model AuthorViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id="someId"        })) {

 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name);
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name);
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name);

 <label> Book </label>
 @{Html.RenderPartial("_BookView", new BookViewModel());}
 <label>One more book...</label>
 @{Html.RenderPartial("_BookView", new BookViewModel());}
}
```

Partial view:

```
@model BookViewModel
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title);
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title);
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title);
```

AuthorViewModel:

```
public class AuthorViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

BookViewModel:

```
public class BookViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public String Title { get; set; }
}
```

So when it renders - it looks right, but validation is the same for all books. An I need to have a lot of books(say to add them dynamically) for author and each one have to be independent and "validatable".

How can I perform such behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have a collection of `BookViewModel` in your `AuthorViewModel`. That way the names and ids will be unique.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your answer the first time.. :)

Comment: I've tried it , but it doesn't help :( I've used a list of BookViewModel and render its elements, but the validation were still same for all books.

Comment: Sorry,it works when render books in loop. Seems like i did something wrong earlier. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could update your AuthorViewModel to have a List of BookViewModel. In the View, iterate over the list and create the necessary fields for the booktitles.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to model bind to a list.
Its pretty simple to implement, have a look at [Phil Haacks post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) here.
He uses the old mvc views, but the same idea works fine for razor