# Can we call single partial view multiple time on a main view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on dashboard. In which I want 4 partial view. All that partial view display same kind of data but on different criteria.
My Dashboard contain:
1) Recent requests
2) Pending Requests
3) Approved Requests
4) High Priority Requests
All view contain data like, id, name of client, name of employee, requested date.
I am just eager to know that can I use single partial view(because all has same model data) many times on a Main View?

Comment: You could try it. And see that it works.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Ok. Let me try.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378564/multiple-partial-views-based-on-same-model

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use single partial view multiple times on a main view,pass parameters to the controller action using `ViewDataDictionary` to distinguish between partial view types in your case 1) Recent requests 2) Pending Requests 3) Approved Requests 4) High Priority Requests.

Yo need to have common viewmodel for this